# How do you setup this proof?

Tags: proof-verification

I have the following problem and I don’t know if I’m even setting it up right.  Any help is much appreciated!

I’m given:
Let U be any set and let P(U) be the power set of U.
Prove that for every A ∈ P(U) there is a unique B ∈ P(U) such that for every C ∈ P(U), C\A = C ∩ B.

I’m setting it up as follows but again, I don’t know if this is right:
∀A ∈ P(U) ∃!B ∈ P(U) (∀A ∈ P(U)(C\A = C ∩ B).

Now…I don’t know if this is saying that there is one B set in total that will solve C\A = C ∩ B for every A and C (which I am thinking this isn’t possible) or is it saying that for every iteration of A and C we use, there is a unique B.  In other words, for instance A1 and C1 we have a unique B1 and then for instance A2 and C2 we have a unique B2.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: B is the complement of A. Why do you want to first formalize the information?

Comment: Thanks Casper.  Formalizing it is part of the exercise.

Comment: Ok. Your formalization is correct except for what I think is a typo: $\forall A\in P(U)\exists ! B\in P(U)\forall C\in P(U)(C\setminus A=C\cap B)$